# Retrieving more than one row of data using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, row

I'm trying to create a function that runs a query that returns all of the data located in my MySQL database.

My current code only returns the one row of data (there are 7)

```
function staff_get() {
    $this->load->database();
    $sql = 'SELECT * from Staff';
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $data = $query->row();
    $this->response($data, 200);
}
```

I'd imagine it has something to do with the line "$data = $query->row();" however I've tried switching "row" with "array" but this doesn't work. The text is designed to come out as plaintext so that I can manipulate it using a jQuery template.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: It's not easy to answer, since we don't know what class `$this->db` is. Are you using a framework or an ORM? If not, editing the `database` method into your question might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encase the results in a while loop. Something along the lines of this.

```
function staff_get() {
    $this->load->database();
    $sql = 'SELECT * from Staff';
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    while($data = $query->row()) {
        $this->response($data, 200);
    }
}
```